# Kivy: how to keep selected a RecycleView list item moved with an up or down button so it can be further moved?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

The code below displays a list of selectable items. After selecting an item, it can be moved up or down in the list using the adequate button. After an item has been moved, it does not remain selected so that it can be moved again. I was not able to find out how to solve this problem.

[image: Executing the code ...]

kivyrecycleview_movebuttons.kv file

```
<KivyRecycleView>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    recycleViewList: recycleView_list
    moveUpButton: moveUp_Button
    moveDownButton: moveDown_Button
    boxLayoutContainingRV: boxlayout_recycleview

    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        height: "28dp"
        Button:
            id: moveUp_Button
            text: "^"
            size_hint_x: 1
            on_press: root.moveUpSelItem()
        Button:
            id: moveDown_Button
            text: "v"
            size_hint_x: 1
            on_press: root.moveDownSelItem()

    BoxLayout:
        id: boxlayout_recycleview
        size_hint_y: 0.8
        height: "60dp"
        RecycleView:
            id: recycleView_list
            scroll_y: 0 # forces scrolling to list bottom after adding an entry
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect" # prevents overscrolling
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(15) # height of list line
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: 0.5
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: False
                touch_multiselect: False

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1) if self.selected else (.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

kivyrecycleview_movebuttons.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

# RecycleView related imports
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    # required to authorise unselecting a selected item
    touch_deselect_last = BooleanProperty(True)

class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index

        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        if not self.selected and not is_selected:
            # case when adding a new list item
            return
        elif self.selected and not is_selected:
            # toggling from selected to unselected
            self.selected = False
            rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = -1

        else:
            # toggling from unselected to selected
            self.selected = not self.selected
            rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = index

class KivyRecycleView(BoxLayout):
    recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = -1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyRecycleView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.populateList()

    def populateList(self):
        for i in range(6):
            listEntry = {'text': 'line {}'.format(i)}
            self.recycleViewList.data.append(listEntry)

    def moveUpSelItem(self):
        oldIndex = self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex
        newIndex = oldIndex - 1
        requestTotalNumber = len(self.recycleViewList.data)

        if newIndex < 0:
            # if first line request is moved up, it is moved at the end of the
            # request history list
            newIndex = requestTotalNumber - 1

        self.moveItemInList(list=self.recycleViewList.data, oldIndex=oldIndex, newIndex=newIndex)

    def moveDownSelItem(self):
        oldIndex = self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex
        newIndex = oldIndex + 1
        requestTotalNumber = len(self.recycleViewList.data)

        if newIndex == requestTotalNumber:
            # if last line request is moved down, it is moved at the beginning of the
            # request history list
            newIndex = 0

        self.moveItemInList(list=self.recycleViewList.data, oldIndex=oldIndex, newIndex=newIndex)

    def moveItemInList(self, list, oldIndex, newIndex):
        list.insert(newIndex, list.pop(oldIndex))

class KivyRecycleView_moveButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self): # implicitely looks for a kv file of name kivyrecycleview.kv which is
                     # class name without App, in lowercases

        return KivyRecycleView()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbApp = KivyRecycleView_moveButtonsApp()

    dbApp.run()
```

Comment: I would use one property. After click, i would send clicked label text. After any click [up or down] i would run function which changes all label's color to grey and check's property and change clicked labels color to orange. I hope this idea helps you.

Comment: Everything must be handled by modifying the `data`. For every entry in the `data`, you should include a `selected` key. Position in the list is controlled by position in the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments above. Here's a solution which works (tested on Windows 10 and on Android). The modifications in comparison with the initial code are  highlithed by the # <<------ comment ! I am sure there exists as simpler solution ...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

# RecycleView related imports
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    # required to authorise unselecting a selected item
    touch_deselect_last = BooleanProperty(True)

class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.rv = rv                            #<<------
        self.index = index

        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            if self.rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex == self.index: #<<------
                self.selected = False                                          #<<------
                self.rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = -1          #<<------
            else:                                                              #<<------
                self.rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = self.index  #<<------
            
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)


    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        if rv.parent.parent.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex == index: #<<------
            is_selected = True                                   #<<------
            self.selected = False                                #<<------
        else:                                                    #<<------
            is_selected = False                                  #<<------
            self.selected = True                                 #<<------
    
        if not self.selected and not is_selected:
            # case when adding a new list item
            return
        elif self.selected and not is_selected:
            # toggling from selected to unselected
            self.selected = False                   #<<------
        else:
            # toggling from unselected to selected
            self.selected = not self.selected       #<<------


class KivyRecycleView(BoxLayout):
    recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = -1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyRecycleView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # setting RecycleView list item height from config
        self.populateList()

    def populateList(self):
        for i in range(6):
            listEntry = {'text': 'line {}'.format(i)}
            self.recycleViewList.data.append(listEntry)

    def moveUpSelItem(self):
        oldIndex = self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex
    
        if oldIndex == -1:                                  #<<------
            return
        
        newIndex = oldIndex - 1
        itemTotalNumber = len(self.recycleViewList.data)
        
        if newIndex < 0:
            # if first line request is moved up, it is moved at the end of the
            # request history list
            newIndex = itemTotalNumber - 1
        
        self.moveItemInList(list=self.recycleViewList.data, oldIndex=oldIndex, newIndex=newIndex)
        self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = newIndex          #<<------

    def moveDownSelItem(self):
        oldIndex = self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex
    
        if oldIndex == -1:                                  #<<------
            return
        
        newIndex = oldIndex + 1
        itemTotalNumber = len(self.recycleViewList.data)
        
        if newIndex == itemTotalNumber:
            # if last line request is moved down, it is moved at the beginning of the
            # request history list
            newIndex = 0
        
        self.moveItemInList(list=self.recycleViewList.data, oldIndex=oldIndex, newIndex=newIndex)
        self.recycleViewCurrentSelIndex = newIndex          #<<------

    def moveItemInList(self, list, oldIndex, newIndex):
        list.insert(newIndex, list.pop(oldIndex))

class KivyRecycleView_moveButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self): # implicitely looks for a kv file of name kivyrecycleview.kv which is
                     # class name without App, in lowercases

        return KivyRecycleView()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbApp = KivyRecycleView_moveButtonsApp()

    dbApp.run()
```